# Telegram.org error: 'Invalid msgs_ack query', u'error_code': -500

Tags: api, telegram

I'm in the process of implementing `msgs_acks` back to the telegram server for "content" messages sent with a response received. I get the above error right off the bat, after the first attempt at acknowledgment to the first content message (`initConnection` using `getNearestDc`, wrapped by `invokeWithLayer`). The sequence of events are listed below. What am I doing out of sequence?

The outgoing message_id is: 6337647283454888960L, which is what I am trying to ack. `-->` is sent TO the server, `<--` is returned FROM the server.

## psuedo code of initConnection call

```
--> ('method_call: ', 'invokeWithLayer', {'query': ['initConnection', 'query': 'getNearestDc']})
(' message_id:       ', 6337647283454888960L)
```

## result of initConnection

```
<--('TL deserialize: x = ', {'MessageContainer': [
{'msg': {u'new_session_created': {u'first_msg_id': 6337647283454888960L, u'unique_id': -8353387387127432890L, u'server_salt': -717652021221374449L}}, 'seqno': 1, 'msg_id': 6337647285940375553L}, 
{'msg': {u'msgs_ack': {u'msg_ids': [6337647283454888960L]}}, 'seqno': 2, 'msg_id': 6337647285940441089L}]})
```

## result of getNearestDc

```
<--('TL deserialize: x = ', {u'req_msg_id': 6337647283454888960L, u'result': {u'nearest_dc': 3, u'country': 'US', u'this_dc': 1}})
```

## attempt to ack back to the server for getNearestDc

```
-->('method_call: ', 'msgs_ack', {'msg_ids': [6337647283454888960L]})
(' message_id:       ', 6337647284623120384L)
```

## error!

```
('TL deserialize: x = ', {u'req_msg_id': 6337647284623120384L, u'result': {u'error_message': 'Invalid msgs_ack query', u'error_code': -500}})
```

Comment: Pretty quiet here, does no one have an answer?

Comment: sending msg_acks should be quite straightforward. see below.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to explain this is as follows:

1. Setup a `dispatch_timer` for handling pending msg_ids, it should fire say every 2-3 minutes
2. Every inbound message you receive has a msg_id
3. In your main receive loop, collate these msg_ids into a `msg_id_list`
4. Each time you send a new request to the server, if you have pending msg_ids in your `msg_id_list`, add them to the message(s) you are about to send in a *message container*. Clear the `msg_id_list`
5. If the `dispatch_timer` fires, and you have `msg_id_list` `count > 0`, then simple send `msgs_ack(msg_id_list)`. Clear the `msg_id_list`

I have used this method to successfully handle msg_acks without any issues.

Comment: I can try that.

Comment: Can you please tell me why the logic I have above _doesn't_ work? My iterative thinking is if I can get the simplest case to work, like above, I can move on to a more complicated case, like your suggestion. My code above seems to be exactly what is asked for in the documentation but I must be missing something.

Comment: why not include the msg_ack as part of the next request in a container ?

Comment: If that is the only workable solution then I will have to do that. I didn't start that way because containers are more complex than simple requests so I figured starting simple then moving toward more complex would validate the documentation and increase my understanding. If your suggestion, which I appreciate, is the correct process then the documentation requires updating.

Comment: you will notice that Telegram uses containers for a lot of their messages, it enables them pack messages together in one RPC call. You can do same if you implement containers , then have a send_message variant that automatically uses containers if you are sending multiple messages. That's how i implemented mine

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the `'Invalid msgs_ack query'` error message had nothing to do with sequence numbers. I improperly serialized the msg ids vector, so the query was indeed invalid.

Once I got that corrected I got another error: `'error_code': 64`, which indicates an invalid container. At least it knows it's a container! I'll try a few things to correct the container and post another question if I run into trouble.